# Twitter Bootstrap Glyphicons partial opacity in IE8 and below

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, opacity, glyphicons

I'm using [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap)'s glyphicons in a project and want them to become partially transparent on :hover. Of course everything works as expected in Chrome, FF, Safari and even in IE9+.

In IE7 and IE8 however, the opacity makes the icons look horrible. Below are the essentials for testing:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <style>
            #icon {
                margin: 50px;
            }

            #icon:hover {
                -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=70)";
                filter: alpha(opacity=70);
                opacity: 0.7;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <i id="icon" class="icon-search"></i>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the order around so that the fallbacks are after the actual declaration.

```
#icon:hover {

opacity: 0.7;
filter: alpha(opacity=70);
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=70)";

}
```

Comment: unfortunately that did not help, also quirksmode.org [recommends](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/opacity.html) a different order. Did you test your css in IE7 or 8?

Comment: I didn't as I'm on my work Mac today. To be honest, getting stuff like this to look well in old browsers may be impossible. I would consider using something like jQuery to see if there's an improvement:

Comment: I think you get to the conclusion that it may be impossible a bit fast. Especially if you didn't actually test it. I don't see why "something like jQuery" would help me?

Comment: I'm speaking from experience with previous projects where I have wanted to achieve the same effect. When I used jQuery's $(#element).css("opacity",value) to toggle the level of opacity instead of #element:hover {}, I got better results in old versions of IE. Why it worked for me then, I don't know. It wasn't perfect but it was better. This is why I suggested a JS solution like jQuery might help you.